# Make Discord bot play sound from a direct url

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

I want to make a discordpy bot that plays audio files from a specific link on the internet, rather than from a local directory. It seems that all the other examples use ytdl, but those are for video streaming sites. How should I go about  doing this?

````
    if(voice_channel != None):
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('http://website/001.mp3'), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
    else:
        await ctx.send("Join a voice channel first.")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. People use youtube-dl to get the direct url. So if you have the url just give do it like you did. BTW i would recommend using FFmpegPCMAudio inside PCMVolumeTransformer so you can easily change volume later. Hope i helped. Have a great day!